# Removing Tax and tax computation based on If else statement

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, tax

How can I remove the Tax/GST based on Account Details Dropdown Group plus the fact that the computation must also be correct.

This is the Account details
[image]

If Group is ICT then it should hide or remove tax/gst in order totals which is below
[image]

And the Grand Total must be correct as well.

I just need which files to edit then after that I can squeeze my way in.